# "We passed through (the bridge)" - can "through" be used on a road?

Tags: prepositions

We just drove through the bridge.

My son asked me, "Where is the bridge"

> "We passed through it."

Can the preposition "through" be used on a road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through, as used in your example, implies a level of contact between a stationary object and a moving object.  "We drove through the bridge," indicates the bridge was "blocking" the road somehow and that you pushed through the blockage to the other side.

Roads and bridges generally use over, under, on, and off.

> "We drove over the bridge," would mean you crossed the bridge.
>
> "We drove under the bridge," means the bridge was above you and you passed under.
>
> "We drove on the bridge," means some part of your drive included being on a bridge.
>
> "We drove off the bridge," could mean you crossed a bridge and exited at the bridge's end.  It would more likely mean you crashed **through** the bridge's guardrail and crashed into the water below.

Comment: There was a question posted several months ago regarding "in the road", "off the road", and "on the road".  That question might provide a bit more insight on prepositions to use with roads.  There will be slight differences between roads and bridges.  Things can be "in" a road for example but not in a bridge.  And driving off roads and bridges are two entirely different things.

Comment: There are covered bridges that we drive through... http://www.nytimes.com/2003/03/23/travel/over-the-river-and-through-the-bridge.html

Comment: @ColleenV -- True, we can drive through covered things -- tunnels and covered bridges.  I imagine it has something to do with the perceived solidity of those objects as opposed to the openness of bridges and roads.